# VAT rates for international

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to sell at the international level, I am looking for the VAT rate or extensions for magento. I sell material goods

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I am looking for an extension that gere VAT automatically for all countries of the world. as I sell internationally. I would like an extensions.